# Show custom post along with default post

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type named "image". Now my theme shows posts on homepage in three parameters- Fresh, Featured, Random(i'm feeling lucky).
How can i add custom posts in there. 
here is the front-page file - [front-page.php](http://pastebin.com/6ZBEQhAT)

Answer (score 0):

To show custom post type on a page, try something like this

```
//place code to display the title here
if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'posttypename' ){
  //place code to display fields here
} else {
  //place code to display excerpt here
}
```

Comment: i want to show with other post. Not individually, and as per theme feature, i want to show it on fresh(new),featured(top voted), random(i'm feeling lucky). See the front-page.php